# How to make a log file in Angular?

Tags: angular, logging

How is that possible to create a log file?

Right now I log with console.log() but I need it to be saved.

Never done this before, maybe possible to write the logs in to a txt file in remote location like Onedrive?

Comment: well.. angular is run inside the client's browser. Unless you want the log txt file to be saved on the client running your application, saving it in angular does not make sense. Logging shall be part of the backend, if you want a monitoring tool that your engineers team can use to gain insights of the user's problem when using your client applications.

Comment: I Understand, actually no problem if the file is saved locally, it is for a testing application on one specific PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael, welcome to SO. The only way that I'm aware of saving locally is not what you'd think, as in a file saved to the file system. Within the browser, you can save data in the form of key-value pairs (including arrays) in either LocalStorage or SessionStorage.

As the name suggests, SessionStorage remains only for the current session, and once the browser tab is closed that session's SessionStorage variables are deleted. With LocalStorage, they persist. In both cases, they are accessible only while on the site - only that website can access them, or you can access them through the browser's developer tools (hit F-12 on the keyboard and they should open up).

In my particular browser, they are under the Application tab of the dev tools.
[image: Edge Browser Tools]

This guide tells you how to use these two storage forms, and you could theoretically use either of them to log to an array or to different variables, or even as a JSON object that is stringified. https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/localstorage-and-sessionstorage-in-angular-app-65cda19283a0

This isn't a typical use of LocalStorage or SessionStorage, but it could work if that's what you want to use. You would have to copy/paste out of the browser tools if you wanted to use the log in some other application, though.